# Sorting a string from part of string using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

- Below is a list of array.I want the strings in array sorted only by airlines. For example below are my
  airlines

> "0:"FZ|Fly Dubai "1:"LH|Lufthansa "2:"IX|Air India Express
>   "3:"6E|IndiGo

- Expected output should be which is sorted only by arilines ( Air
  India Express, Fly Dubai, Lufthansa, Indigo instead of complete
  string

> "0:"IX|Air India Express "1:"FZ|Fly Dubai "2:"LH|Lufthansa
>   "3:"6E|IndiGo

- I have tried something like this

---

```
str = str.split('|');

str = str.sort(function (a,b) {
    if (a === '0' || b === '0')
        return (b === a) ?  0 : (a < b) ? 1 : -1;

    return (a < b) ? -1 : (a === b) ? 0 : 1;
});
```

Comment: Is that how your string is formatted?

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. Just answer this question, What datatype is `"0:"FZ|Fly Dubai "1:"LH|Lufthansa "2:"IX|Air India Express "3:"6E|IndiGo`?

Comment: My requirement is array should sort only from part of string . Expected output should be IX|Air India Express, FZ|Fly Dubai, LH|Lufthansa

Comment: means it should sort based on carriers Air India Express, Lufthansa, IndiGo and should return "0:"FZ|Fly Dubai "1:"LH|Lufthansa "2:"IX|Air India Express "3:"6E|IndiGo as final array

Comment: Is my answer satisfactory or have I misunderstood the requirement.

Comment: yes its satisfactory working perfectly

Comment: You should mark as answer to indicate resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let airlines = [
  "FZ|Fly Dubai", 
  "LH|Lufthansa", 
  "IX|Air India Express", 
  "6E|IndiGo",
];


let sorted = airlines.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.split('|')[1].localeCompare(b.split('|')[1]);
});

console.log(sorted);
```

Answer (score 0):

No jQuery needed.

Assuming `s = '"0:"FZ|Fly Dubai "1:"LH|Lufthansa "2:"IX|Air India Express "3:"6E|IndiGo'`

```
s.split(/\"[^\"]+\"/) // regex parses entries
.filter( // removes invalid entries
    function(a){
        return a.length > 0 && a.indexOf("|") > -1
}).sort( // sorts based on airline name
    function(a,b){
        return a.split("|")[1] > b.split("|")[1]
});
```

To get it back in the initial format, you could then map. ie:

```
let i = 0;
s.split(/\"[^\"]+\"/) // regex parses entries
.filter( // removes invalid entries
    function(a){
        return a.length > 0 && a.indexOf("|") > -1
}).sort( // sorts based on airline name
    function(a,b){
        return a.split("|")[1] > b.split("|")[1]
}).map( // map puts it back in original state, but ordered
    function(z){
        return '"'+(i++).toString()+':"' + z;
});
```